# Python / Pandas Tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First: thank you for the great help so far! I have a question on working with table formatting in iPython.

I currently run this script to print the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) Test for Stationarity:

```
print "Stationarity"
print sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(df['temperature'], maxlag=None, autolag='BIC', regression='c')
```

The output is something like this:

```
Stationarity
(-6.4532219513246361, 1.5054094590984612e-08, 0, 41, {'5%': -2.9351348158036012, '1%': -3.6009833671885199, '10%': -2.6059629803688282}, 1227.2605520289471*)
```

*(not sure what this value is [Link to Documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.5.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html))

Now, my questions are:

1. How can I automate the calculation for more than one variable? Is it possible to create a list containing the different columns (df['variable1'], df['variable1'], df['variable1'], df['variable1'], ...) that applies the ADF test for each item?
2. How can I put the returning data into a table structure? Something like this:

**ADF Test**

```
Variable      nobs  t-test  p-value                     1%       5%      10%
temperature     41  6.4532  1.5054094590984612e-08  -3.600  -2.9351  -2.6059
variable 2     ...
variable 3     ...
```

(By the way: How to convert "1.5054094590984612e-08" into an accurate number?)

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Can you post raw input data, as for your first question I think this should work, if `col_list` is a list of your variables then `df[col_list].apply(sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller, maxlag=None, autolag='BIC', regression='c')` you can assign these to new columns and then transpose if you want the columns as index values.

Comment: Cool - Questions #1 seems to be solved now! I implemented the script and it works. Can you help me on the second problem?

Comment: Can you some raw data or a link to your data, I have no clue what inputs this is expecting

Comment: As input, you basically only need a list of values (time series). I can't disclose the data here, but imagine it's a list of 1000+ values between 1 and 30.

Comment: So just a datetimeindex and random values?

Comment: exactly datetimeindex plus a column with the value for each day.

Comment: OK, I'll knock something up, basically my approach would be to just walk the series/df that is returned from my previous code snippet and then pull the individual components out and append them row by row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I basically knocked up some dummy data, basically I build a dict for each col to store the adf test results and then construct a df for each result:

```
In [12]:

df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2014,1,1), end = dt.datetime(2014,6,1)))
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
df['a'] = np.random.randint(0,30,len(df.index))
df['b'] = np.random.randint(0,30,len(df.index))
​
result={}
for col in df:
    result[col] = ts.adfuller(df[col], maxlag=None, autolag='BIC', regression='c')
result
Out[12]:
{'a': (-14.5378299332063,
  5.2041541962613174e-27,
  0,
  151,
  {'1%': -3.4744158894942156,
   '10%': -2.5770812758212358,
   '5%': -2.8808783827710589},
  983.29106640612281),
 'b': (-12.247140023284922,
  9.7254933298555022e-23,
  0,
  151,
  {'1%': -3.4744158894942156,
   '10%': -2.5770812758212358,
   '5%': -2.8808783827710589},
  983.89321857804237)}
In [29]:

df_result = pd.DataFrame()
​
for k,v in result.items():
    df_result = df_result.append(pd.DataFrame(
            data={'nobs':v[3], 't-test':v[0], 'p-value':v[1], '1%':v[4]['1%'], '5%':v[4]['5%'], '10%':v[4]['10%']},
            index=[k]))
df_result.index.name = 'temperature'
df_result
Out[29]:
                   1%       10%        5%  nobs       p-value    t-test
temperature                                                            
a           -3.474416 -2.577081 -2.880878   151  5.204154e-27 -14.53783
b           -3.474416 -2.577081 -2.880878   151  9.725493e-23 -12.24714
```

Comment: It seems to work for except that it rounds up all items. "-3.474416" is "-3", "-2.577081" is "-2"...

Comment: That could be a display issue, what happens when you print `result` like in my code above?

Comment: Those values are correct (16 digits after the decimal). I have no idea why the values in the df_results table are rounded

Comment: I think this is a display issue, what does `df['1%']` show or better `df['1%'].iloc[0]` show?.

Comment: df_result['1%'] shows "-4" for all values, df_result['1%'].iloc[0] shows "-3.6009833671885199" (dtype: float64)

Comment: It's just a display issue then you can override this `pd.set_option('display.precision, 20)` the default is 7

Comment: Yes, tried that one already but it still rounds all values :/

Comment: This may be a bug, would be worth posting on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format fixed the problem!